# How to show multiple activities of an app in the android sharesheet?

Tags: android, share

I should be able to show different activities of my application in the android sharesheet like the example image shown below.

[image: example image, instagram]

Should I add a new activity? And how is it configured in androidmanifest.xml?

This is the MainActivity part of the androidmanifest.xml, where I have added intent to receive text and images. Now only one icon is shown in the sharesheet.

```
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Comment: Just move the intent filters to the respective activities. Those activities will be shown in the chooser if it matches the filter

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple activities and for each activity add an intent filter. You can add label attribute for `<intent-filter>` to provide a custom label for each activity `<intent-filter android:label="My Label 1">`

```
<activity android:name=".BroadcastReceiverActivity1" >
    <intent-filter android:label="My Label 1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".BroadcastReceiverActivity2" >
    <intent-filter android:label="My Label 2">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```